# Image not loading completely using onload

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, onload

`canvasArray` contains the split image, when opened in browser the `<canvas>` elements are supposed to be displayed in a table e.g 3x3
First time opening page an emtpy table is rendered on screen (issue), when clicked again it displayed the `<canvas>` elements correctly, presumably because they are cached
How come they are not displaying first time? I tried using `ctx.drawImage(img,xoffset,yoffset);` twice in the code, inside the `onload` event and outside
Thinking being if image doesnt draw correctly outside the loop, once `onload` event fires it will try again, but it does not ..

```
Image URL<input type="text" id="image" value="images/hippo.jpg"/><br>


var canvasArray = Project.split( $("#image").val() , rowCount * rowCount); 
 // eg Project.split("https://image.com/funny.jpg, 3, 3");

var Project = {
  split: function(imgsrc, tiles) {

    var img = new Image(),
        canvasArray = new Array(),
        imgWidth,
        imgHeight,
        r,g,b = 0;
    img.onload = function(){
        xoffset = 0,
        offset = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < tiles; i++){

            //create canvas element and set attributes and get the canvas context
            canvasArray[i] = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvasArray[i].setAttribute('width', tileW);
            canvasArray[i].setAttribute('height', tileH);    
            canvasArray[i].setAttribute('id', 'canvas'+i);
            var ctx = canvasArray[i].getContext('2d');

            ctx.drawImage(img,xoffset,yoffset);

            //if i is a multiple of the total number of tiles to a row,
            //move down a column and reset the row_col
            if((i + 1) % row_col == 0){
                yoffset -= tileH;
                xoffset =0;
            }else{
                //otherwise move across the image
                xoffset -= tileW; 
            }
        }
    };
    img.src = imgsrc;   

    //get the number of tiles in a row or column (row == column )
    var row_col = Math.sqrt(tiles),
        tileH = img.height / row_col,
        tileW = img.width / row_col,
        canvasArray = [tiles];

    var xoffset = 0,
        yoffset = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < tiles; i++){

        //create canvas element and set attributes and get the canvas context
        canvasArray[i] = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvasArray[i].setAttribute('width', tileW);
        canvasArray[i].setAttribute('height', tileH);
        canvasArray[i].setAttribute('id', 'canvas'+i);
        var ctx = canvasArray[i].getContext('2d');

        ctx.drawImage(img,xoffset,yoffset);

        //if i is a multiple of the total number of tiles to a row,
        //move down a column and reset the row_col
        if((i + 1) % row_col == 0){
            yoffset -= tileH;
            xoffset =0;
        }else{
            //otherwise move across the image
            xoffset -= tileW; 
        }
    }

    return canvasArray;
}};
```

Comment: the image can be cached, so you should also check complete property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `complete` of img, select image itself instead of `val`, calculate image dimensions inside onload handler, also as image loading is asynchronous operation, you need use callback, instead of return array:

```
// eg Project.split("https://image.com/funny.jpg, 3*3,function(canvasArray)");
var Project = {
    split: function(imgsrc, tiles, callback) {

        var canvasArray = new Array(),
            imgWidth, imgHeight, r, g, b = 0;
        var split = function() {
            console.log(1);
            var row_col = Math.sqrt(tiles),
                tileH = Math.round(img.height / row_col),
                tileW = img.width / row_col,

                xoffset = 0,
                yoffset = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < tiles; i++) {
                //create canvas element and set attributes and get the canvas context
                canvasArray[i] = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvasArray[i].setAttribute('width', tileW);
                canvasArray[i].setAttribute('height', tileH);
                canvasArray[i].setAttribute('id', 'canvas' + i);
                var ctx = canvasArray[i].getContext('2d');

                ctx.drawImage(img, xoffset, yoffset);

                //if i is a multiple of the total number of tiles to a row,
                //move down a column and reset the row_col
                if ((i + 1) % row_col == 0) {
                    yoffset -= tileH;
                    xoffset = 0;
                } else {
                    //otherwise move across the image
                    xoffset -= tileW;
                }
            }
            callback(canvasArray);
        };
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imgsrc;
        console.log(img.complete);
            if (img.complete) {split()} else  $(img).load(split);
    }
};
var tn = 3;
$("button").bind('click', function() {
    Project.split($("#image").val(), tn * tn, function(canvasArray) {
        for (var i in canvasArray) {
            $('body').append(canvasArray[i]);
            if ((i * 1 + 1) % tn == 0) {
                $('body').append($('<br>'))
            }
        }
        console.log(canvasArray);
    });


});

$("button").click();​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ezAqY/1/)

Comment: no luck with this, clearing the cache and loading page showing empty cells, clicking again the images are there in the cells

Comment: oh... `$("#image").val()` that would be problem, use `$("#image").attr('src')` or `$("#image").get(0)` , in code not set src again, and all would be fine

Comment: this does not work, `$("#image")` is actually an `<input type="text">` element, not an image .. `Image URL<input type="text" id="image" value="images/hippo.jpg"/><br>`

Comment: fixed, it need callback to return value, see the demo

Answer (score 0):

Before I use images in a canvas, I make sure they are loaded using the [Imagesloaded jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).

You can select any DOM element on the page, or you can dynamically create the images and add them to a hidden DOM element then you can have your callback function executed whenever the images have finished loading (including failing)

```
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = imgsrc;
 $(document.body).append(img);
 $(document.body).imagesLoaded( [ callback ] );
```

I use this plugin because there are a handful of issues and edge cases where a browser will not report an image as being fully loaded.  This includes browser back navigates, primed cache that has exceeded the disk limit, mobile browsers which never fire cached images, and a bunch more.

Comment: do you know what the licensing requirements are for 'Imagesloaded jQuery Plugin'? do not see them listed on site. Would like to minimize the number of third party plugins our project depends on

Comment: I found `LICENSED UNDER THE MIT LICENSE` but that was all.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone with eicto's answer as it does not require additional libraries